# C++ Console - Search a client by a specific number

Tags: c++, struct, binary

I'm really new to C++, in fact, this is my first project and this is my first time playing around with C++.

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[50];
    char morada[100];
    char codpostal[8];
    char localidade[25];
    int telefone;
    int nContribuinte;
} CLIENTE;
```

I'm using this `f = fopen("PSI.dat", "wb");` where I keep the information saved. This is how I add info to it:

```
FILE *f;
int i, x;
CLIENTE Clt;

// ler dados
printf("            Nome: ");   cin >> Clt.nome;
printf("          Morada: ");   cin >> Clt.morada;
printf("      Cod-Postal: ");   cin >> Clt.codpostal;
printf("      Localidade: ");   cin >> Clt.localidade;
printf(" No Contribuinte: ");   cin >> Clt.nContribuinte;
printf("        Telefone: ");   cin >> Clt.telefone;

// gravar no ficheiro
fwrite(&Clt, sizeof(Clt), 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

**Question**: How do I search PSI.dat for an existing `Clt.nContribuinte` that user asks for in `scanf("%d",&i);`

Comment: First thing to do is drop the C-isms! `FILE*`, `printf`, `fopen`, `typedef struct`, `char[]`..yikes. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition is seriously correct.

Comment: since this is for a school project I kinda have to use these... no other option

Comment: Then you are not learning C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this, you will probably need to tweak it slightly.

This is a C++ solution, not a C solution. @BoundaryImposition's remarks are absolutely correct and warrant a rethinking of the problem that matches the idioms, expressiveness, and facilities of the language you are learning.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Client {
    std::string nome;
    std::string morada;
    std::string codpostal;
    std::string localidade;
    int telefone;
    int nContribuinte;
};

Client get_search_criteria() {
    auto c = Client{};

    std::cout << "            Nome: ";
    std::cin >> c.nome;
    std::cout << "          Morada: ";
    std::cin >> c.morada;
    std::cout << "      Cod-Postal: ";
    std::cin >> c.codpostal;
    std::cout << "      Localidade: ";
    std::cin >> c.localidade;
    std::cout << " No Contribuinte: ";
    std::cin >> c.nContribuinte;
    std::cout << "        Telefone: ";
    std::cin >> c.telefone;

    return c;
}

int main() {
    auto criteria = get_search_criteria();

    auto infile = std::ifstream{"PSI.dat"};
    int line;
    while (infile >> line) {
        if (line == criteria.nContribuinte) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I don't write C++ often.

Comment: That is just perfect! I just needed that `while` loop for my problem. One small thing, `line` has to be `int line;` cause `criteria.nContribuinte` is an integer value. I'm getting the line number where the information is found and using `fseek(f, i * sizeof(CLIENTE), SEEK_SET);` and `fread(&Clt, sizeof(CLIENTE), 1, f);` to get the information. It works :) Thanks mate

Comment: Fixed to use int. Avoid fseek. Glad I could help.